# php mail function not working in windows 7

Tags: php, email

I have major problem with php  mail() function.

Before my platform is windows xp. In my company we have a microsoft smtp server(I hope so).
At this time the mail() function works perfectly. After some days i switched to windows 7 because of some reasons. This was where my problems begins. When i'm testing my old applications which ran very softly in xp, but not in windows7. Particularly mail() function is taking more execution time and keep on running like deadlock. After long back it displays below message

**Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 secondsd exceeded in D:\wamp\www\ixe_bwf_apr03\writefile.php on line 265**

the code in the line 265 is

```
$ok = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);
```

if i'm commented this line rest of the code is working nicely. Even i tried mail function alone but, same problem is trailing me. But the interesting thing is after the fatal error after some time i'm getting mail.
Please someone help me to sort out this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is there in `$returnpath` ? Can you post the `var_dump` of it ?

Comment: SMTP misconfiguration looks quite possible here. Would you share your phpinfo() related to smtp?

Comment: @blue i have these values in php info(). `SMTP : ***.***.co.in, PORT : 25`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: How could i use var_dump as i'm getting fata error.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: $returnpath is nothing but Reply-to value configured in.

Comment: Have you tried removing that variable and give a shot ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your htaccess file. You just need to extend your execution time of the scripts

```
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
    
    php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
    php_value memory_limit 300M
    php_value max_execution_time 259200
    php_value max_input_time 259200
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
    </IfModule>
```

There are many other ways to achieve this. You can also use `ini_set()` function

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: _You should find the reason why the script is timing out instead of increasing the limit furthermore._

Comment: i really doubt increasing timeout will help anything here.

Comment: Thnx for ur suggestion.I should have thought of that @Shankar Damodaran . May be something gone wrong while installing php in win7

Comment: I tried by increasing the time. But still it's no use. It's executing till the time limit. After as usual i'm getting Fatal Error.